# Horizontal custom scroller - not working - div#news1 total width not set by browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I am building a horizontal and vertical scroller for a website I am currently developing. The vertical one is working great, with no problems, and I have also managed to incorporate jQuery to control it's animation.
The problem lies in the horizontal scroller. To control it I need one important data: the total length of the `div#news1` content (to use in the `comp` variable in function `mexer`). However the browser only returns me the `clientHeight`, which is the same as it's container (`div#cont1`). I need this to be generated automatically and properly by the browser because my website will have dynamic data inserted into it (PHP).
Why does this happen? What I am doing wrong? How can I fix it?

Here is the code for the test file:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="JS/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

.container {
    width:250px;
    height:250px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    border:3px solid #666;
}

.container1 {
    width:400px;
    height:125px;
    overflow:hidden;
    border:3px solid #666;
}
.botao {
    border:3px solid #666;
    background-color:#CCC;
    padding:3px 3px 3px 3px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    cursor:pointer;
}
</style>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="container" id="cont">
<div id="news" style="position:relative">
<p><img src="a6.jpg" height="125" width="250" /></p>
<p><img src="a6.jpg" height="125" width="250" /></p>
<p><img src="a6.jpg" height="125" width="250" /></p>
<p><img src="a6.jpg" height="125" width="250" /></p>
<p><img src="a6.jpg" height="125" width="250" /></p>
<p><img src="a6.jpg" height="125" width="250" /></p>
</div>
</div>
<p><span id="botao1" onClick="mexe(1)" class="botao">Para cima</span></p>
<p><span id="botao2" onClick="mexe(2)" class="botao">Para baixo</span></p>

<div class="container1" id="cont1" style="float:left">
<div id="news1" style="position:relative">
<div style="float:left"><img src="fotosdojoao/1.png" height="125" width="250"></div>
<div style="float:left"><img src="fotosdojoao/2.png" height="125" width="250"></div>
<div style="float:left"><img src="fotosdojoao/3.png" height="125" width="250"></div>
<div style="float:left"><img src="fotosdojoao/4.png" height="125" width="250"></div>
</div>
</div>
<p><span id="botao3" onClick="mexer(1)" class="botao">Esquerda</span></p>
<p><span id="botao4" onClick="mexer(2)" class="botao">Direita</span></p>
<script type="text/javascript">
var topo;
var baixo;
var avanco;
var altura;


function mexe(direcao)
{
    topo=Number(document.getElementById("news").style.top.substr(0,document.getElementById("news").style.top.length-2));
    baixo=Number(document.getElementById("news").style.top.substr(0,document.getElementById("news").style.bottom.length-2));
    avanco=Number(document.getElementById("cont").clientHeight);
    altura=Number(document.getElementById("news").clientHeight)-avanco+30;


if (direcao==1 && topo<0)
    {
        if((topo+avanco)>=0)
        {
            topo=0;
        }
        else
        {
        topo=topo+avanco;
        }
    //document.getElementById("news").style.top=topo+"px";
    }
    
if(direcao==2)
    {
        if((topo-avanco)*(-1)>=altura)
        {
            topo=altura*-1;
        }
        else
        {
        topo=topo-avanco;
        }
        //document.getElementById("news").style.top=topo+"px";
    }
}

$(document).ready(function()
  {
  $("#botao1").click(function(){
    $("#news").animate({top:topo+"px"},"normal","swing");
  });
  $("#botao2").click(function(){
    $("#news").animate({top:topo+"px"},"normal","swing");
  });
});



function mexer(direcao)
{
    esq=Number(document.getElementById("news1").style.left.substr(0,document.getElementById("news1").style.left.length-2));
    passagem=Number(document.getElementById("cont1").clientWidth);
    comp=Number(document.getElementById("news1").style.width.substr(0,document.getElementById("news1").style.width.length-2));
    maximo=comp-passagem+20;


if (direcao==1 && esq<0)
    {
        if((esq+passagem)>=0)
        {
            esq=0;
        }
        else
        {
        esq=esq+passagem;
        }
    document.getElementById("news1").style.left=esq+"px";
    }
    
if(direcao==2)
    {
        if((esq-passagem)*(-1)>=maximo)
        {
            esq=maximo*-1;
        }
        else
        {
        esq=esq-passagem;
        }
        document.getElementById("news1").style.left=esq+"px";
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Because its natural of elements to "fall" down, its never a problem to get the height, but the width is much more tricky. You need to find the width and number of elements which together makes the total width.

Comment: Understood the way to make it work. But do you, or anyone knows why this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure it's what you wanted, but to set/get the width you can do it like this:

```
//get width of an item
var itemWidth = $('#news1 > div:first').width();
//count number of items
var itemsCount = $('#news1 > div').length;
//width * count = width
var containerWidth = itemWidth * itemsCount;
alert(containerWidth);
```

You can set it directly doing

```
$('#news1').width(containerWidth);
```

Or use it when you make the scrolling.

Since it's not in english i have a hard time understanding how it works :/